# F# type functions and a [<GeneralizableValue>] attribute

Tags: generics, f#, attributes, type-systems

What is the difference between this two F# type functions:

```
let defaultInstance1<'a when 'a:(new: unit->'a)> = new 'a()

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let defaultInstance2<'a when 'a:(new: unit->'a)> = new 'a()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let defaultInstance1<'a when 'a:(new: unit->'a)> = new 'a()

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let defaultInstance2<'a when 'a:(new: unit->'a)> = new 'a()

let x1 = defaultInstance1 // value restriction
let x2 = defaultInstance2
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a good blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313200648/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mulambda/archive/2010/05/01/value-restriction-in-f.aspx)).

It takes a bit of reading to get to the `GeneralizableValue` part, but if you get there, I think you will understand it.  :)