# Why isn't my function generalized intuitively?

Tags: types, f#, type-inference

I'm having trouble understanding the behavior of F#'s type inferencer.  The operator `string` relies on static type dispatch at compile-time, and not run-time, which is why something like `let lowerstring = string >> (fun s -> s.ToLowerInvariant())` isn't generalized - the compiler needs to know the type of the argument.  However, I'm seeing some strange-to-me behavior.

With the following definitions:

```
let inline lower (s: string) = s.ToLowerInvariant()

// 'T -> string, constrained to the type of its first use
let lowerstring1 = string >> lower

// Same as above
let lowerstring2 value = value |> string |> lower

// Same as above
let lowerstring3 = box >> string >> lower

// 'a -> string, fully generalized
let lowerstring4 value = value |> box |> string |> lower
```

I observe this behavior:

```
// val token: JToken
// val num: int

let tokstr1 = lowerstring1 token // lowerstring1 now has type JToken -> string
let numstr1 = lowerstring1 num   // Error, doesn't compile

(* As above with lowerstring2 and lowerstring3 *)

let tokstr4 = lowerstring4 token // lowerstring4 now has type 'a -> string
let numstr4 = lowerstring4 num   // no error, works as 'expected'
```

I'm not clear why `lowerstring3` and `lowerstring4` are typechecked differently.  Static constraints seem likely, but if that were the case then shouldn't `lowerstring4` have failed to generalize?  Why should the explicit presence of a function argument make the difference here?

Comment: The first is a _value_, which cannot be generic; the latter is a function, which can. Introduce `inline` and have some real fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# has to codegen down to IL, and since there are no generic 'values' in .NET, functions are only made when they are true syntatic functions (which get generated into a .NET method which can be generic).

(One exception is `[<GeneralizableValueAttribute>]`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963568/f-type-functions-and-a-generalizablevalue-attribute).)